# Elastic Beanstalk Environment for multi-container docker fails to be created due to LaunchWaitCondition

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm gonna set up sample `elasticbeanstalk` environment for `multi-container docker`.
But it is not created due to error.

environment tier: `web-server`
other configuration info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKwBn.png

I want to create sample `elasticbeanstalk` environment for `multi-container docker`.
But the actual is not created.

Here is the error statement.

```
WARN    Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Severe. 
        Initialization in progress (running for 15 minutes). None of the instances are sending data.
ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-at4dw9xg2u-stack' aborted operation. 
        Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].
ERROR   LaunchWaitCondition failed. 
        The expected number of EC2 instances were not initialized within the given time. 
        Rebuild the environment. If this persists, contact support.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by allowing inbound & outbound traffic for default ACL network.
[inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLW6A.png)
[outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFmmW.png)